# Switch monitor configurations on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, external-display

I use one of my PCs for flight simulation as well as for home theater. In case one it has 2 monitors attached, and in case 2 (home theater) a HD TV is being used. All 3 monitors are attached at the same time to the graphics card.

How could it best switch best between different configurations. In case 1 I'd like to have the configuration with monitor 1/2, alternatively I'd like quickly to switch to another config only with the HD TV as primary screen.

A [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/292860/switch-monitor-configurations-on-windows-7) has been asked 6 months back with no full solution yet, so I come up with it again. The comment there of Darius (**Windows + P key**) is the best so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Windows + P key** for a while now, and it is fine.

From above:
A similar question has been asked 6 months back with no full solution yet, so I come up with it again. The comment there of Darius (Windows + P key) is the best so far.